# Simply return a value from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Wondering if you guys can help. I am trying to create a generic component which when called, will return a value.

The code currently stands as follows:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Clients extends Component {
   render () {
      var userEnum = {
      SMALL: 1,
      MEDIUM: 2,
      LARGE: 3,
      properties: {
        1: {name: "Admin", value: 1},
        2: {name: "Manager", value: 2},
        3: {name: "Standard", value: 3}
      }
    };

    const clientName = (value) => {
      return userEnum.properties[value].name
    }
    return null
  }
}

export default Clients
```

and in another component, I try calling the clientName function (done an import too).

```
import ClientHelper from '../../helpers/clients'

    ...
      const test =  ClientHelper.clientName(2)
      console.log(test)
```

I should expect a return value of 'Manager' but I get

> TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__helpers_clients**.a.clientName
>   is not a function

Comment: What is `userEnum`? (Not a jeopardy answer). 
Why is `Client` a react component?

Comment: use client like a regular class not a component. render function in components expects a return value of jsx tags.

Comment: Are you shure that you need precisely React Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the function `clientName` inside the `render` method of the [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) `Clients`. This function is only accessible inside it's scope, the `render` method.
To access the function like you would, by calling the class `Clients` static method `clientName`, you should write it like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Clients extends Component {
    static userEnum = {
        SMALL: 1,
        MEDIUM: 2,
        LARGE: 3,
        properties: {
            1: { name: "Admin", value: 1 },
            2: { name: "Manager", value: 2 },
            3: { name: "Standard", value: 3 }
        }
    };

    static clientName(value) {
        return Clients.userEnum.properties[value].name;
    }
    render() {

        return null;
    }
}

export default Clients
```

If you do not intend to render anything with this class, you do not need react, and can simply create a utility/static class like below:

```
export default class Clients {
    static userEnum = {
        SMALL: 1,
        MEDIUM: 2,
        LARGE: 3,
        properties: {
            1: { name: "Admin", value: 1 },
            2: { name: "Manager", value: 2 },
            3: { name: "Standard", value: 3 }
        }
    };

    static clientName(value) {
        return Clients.userEnum.properties[value].name;
    }
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly! needed to change  static clientName(value) => { to static clientName(value) { for the latter

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited afterwards, I forgot to remove the arrow in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

the function clientName is not a property of your class, but a local function inside the render function and therefore not accessible from the outside.

To solve this, you have to make clientName as well as your userEnum properties of the Clients object, for example in the constructor:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Clients extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.userEnum = {
      SMALL: 1,
      MEDIUM: 2,
      LARGE: 3,
      properties: {
        1: {name: "Admin", value: 1},
        2: {name: "Manager", value: 2},
        3: {name: "Standard", value: 3}
      }
    };
  }
  
  function clientName (value) {
    return this.userEnum.properties[value].name
  }

  function render () {
    return null
  }
}

export default Clients
```